# What does $(f(g)(x)) $ mean?

Tags: functions

I basically need help in understanding what the function of g of x means in lamen's terms. If it were on one side of a question what would that question mean? Simple question, I only need a simple answer, if it would not bother anyone.

Comment: I think you mean $f(g(x))$; if so, this is called [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition).

Comment: But if you really mean $f(g)(x)$, it is possible that $f(g)$ is a function, and that $f(g)(x)$ is the image fo $x$ by that function, though you should probably put parentheses like this: $(f(g))(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean $f(g(x))$, then this is called "function composition". I will use an example to explain what it means. If you have two functions $$f(x)=-2x+1$$ and $$g(x)=x^2+4$$ and you want to find $f(g(3))$, then you would evaluate $g(3)$ first. $$3^2+4=13$$ Then you would evaluate $f(13)$ ($13$ is the result of evaluating $g(3)$). $$-2(13)+1=-25$$ So, $$\boxed{f(g(2))=-25}$$

Answer (score 1):

An example for the second case: In the theory of differential equations, an initial value problem $y'=f(y)$, $y(0)=y_0$ is transformed into an integral equation

$$(T(y))(x)=y_0+\int_0^x f(y(s))\,ds$$

That is, $T$ is a function that has a whole function $y$ as argument and returns a function $y_1=T(y)$. This new function then of course has function values, and they can be written as $y_1(x)=(T(y))(x)$.